# How can I use PHP to grab files from different directories

Tags: php

I understand in HTML, you can use `../../../` to include content which is included in other folders.

I have this PHP code and I'm wondering how can I use ../../../ before header.php?

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("../../../header.php");
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%","Homepage",$buffer);
echo $buffer;
?>
```

Comment: exactly like that. just make sure you're "migrating" to the proper directory...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working

Comment: well, we can't help you with that. we have no idea what your directory structure is, or where the header file is relative to the above script.

Comment: Well, is `header.php` three folders back?  I would consider pushing PHP variables if you are using `include` rather than pulling a template in and running `str_replace`

Comment: header.php is three folders back.

Comment: Do you have error_reporting enabled?  Maybe disable output buffering for now.  Debug it to see what the problem is.   This is where a MVC type framework can shine.  You don't have to worry about relative paths as much if you organize it properly.

Comment: try using  include(dirname( __ FILE __ )."/../../../header.php");  (with no spaces on underscores, this editor puts bold string using undersocres :P)

Comment: @maztch, wrap the code in ` and it won't be converted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [chdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) php function and [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php). im suggest you use constant as source path location..

try this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
chdir("../../../");
$cwd =  rtrim(str_replace("\\", "/", getcwd()), '/').'/';
include($cwd."header.php");
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%","Homepage",$buffer);
echo $buffer;
?>
```

Comment: try to print $cwd. you will see where is current working directory. or you can write your structure files here and i will help you to solve your problem